# I got test idea from former issues. How can I categorize this?

Tags: test-strategy

I'm a newbie in a testing world. I'm confusing about categorizing my work as a formal word of testing.
 The situation is this.

> Our app added video plugin functions in advance at Windows OS. At that time, there were many issues than usual. At this release, We developed iOS version which complying with Windows functions.
>    There was no functional specifications. I set the windows version as a test oracle. So I derived issues from BTS about Windows. And check the issues and followed the step to find if same or similar issues appear.

Now I'm trying to summary testing work. Is it possible to categorize my work as experience-based testing or

Comment: Why do you need to categorize these tests?

Comment: I just want to define what area I'm doing in SW testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of experience-based testing technique is Error Guessing which takes advantage of a tester’s skill, intuition and **experience with similar applications** to identify special tests. So your tests fall into this category but this is more an opinion-based assignment rather that strict rule. Many of testing techniques will apply to few categories at once but knowing the category it is not as important as when to use which technique.